# Special Character added when saving from xml to csv

Tags: xml, csv, special-characters

I am facing a problem when i save a xml file in csv UTF8 comma delimited, a special character is added automatically in first place of first row.
This is also not visible when i see CSV in notepad.

I identified this when i was trying to import my file to DB, the table was showing error as the value of a field was exactly 12 characters in xml and csv and system was saying its more than 12 characters. I checked my csv file in tool exam diff pro and i can see a special character.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVOYm.jpg)
Has anyone ecncountered the same issue. Any quick fixes to this-

See the yellow highlighted character below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3yGC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those characters are a [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) and most editors should recognize them.

If you don't want those, try saving without BOM.

Comment: Thank you Danny for your reply. Saving with Only CSV Comma delimited works but in case i have some Russian Characters in the same field, thn i will lose that information in normal CSV save.

Comment: @DeepanshuDhamija No, you shouldn't lose that information. It's still a utf-8 file, but the optional BOM is removed (of course you still have to save as utf-8, but without the BOM). If you then open the file in utf-8 mode all should be fine.

Comment: @DeepanshuDhamija Ok, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem :)